# ASP MVC setting defining images folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am a newbie in asp mvc, and would like to define links in views to image/content folder in a way so I don't have to change each link if a image folder changes.

Is is possible using ActionLink and routing, bundling or there is a better way to achieve this.

I could not find a good example anywhere so I did not try anything any coding far.

I am thinking of storing a fixed path somewhere, but is that really a mvc type solution?

Comment: Do you mean if you rename the folder?

Comment: @StephenMuecke rename the folder or choose a different one.

Comment: And what does the image/content folder contain - .css files or image files (`.png, .jpg etc) - sorry I'm confused because MVC folder structure has Content and Images folders

Comment: @Would it really hurt if instead /images/ I use content/images that would store all image types ......!?

Comment: Probably not - just wanted to make sure its was for image files and not .css files (where bundling could have been a solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could do this. Here's one approach to extend the `Url.Content()` method.

## 1. Create an extension method

We'll called it `Virtual()`.

```
namespace TestApp.Extensions
{
    public static class UrlHelperExtensions
    {
        private const string _settingPattern = "path:{0}";
        private const string _regexPattern = @"\{\w+\}";

        public static string Virtual(this UrlHelper helper, string url)
        {
            Regex r = new Regex(_regexPattern);
            var matches = r.Matches(url);

            if (matches.Count == 0) return url;

            var sb = new StringBuilder(url);
            var keys = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys;

            foreach (var match in matches)
            {
                string key = match.ToString().TrimStart('{').TrimEnd('}');
                string pattern = string.Format(_settingPattern, key);

                foreach (var k in keys)
                {
                    if (k == pattern)
                    {
                        sb.Replace(match.ToString(), WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(k));
                    }
                }
            }

            return helper.Content(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

## 2. Add settings to the main Web.config

Freely add any paths you want.

```
<add key="path:images" value="~/Content/images" />
<add key="path:scripts" value="~/scripts" />
```

## 3. Add the namespace to the Web.config of your views directory

```
<namespaces>
    <add namespace="TestApp.Extensions"/>
</namespaces>
```

## 4. Use the new method

```
@Url.Virtual("{images}/mypic.png")
```

Output:

```
/Content/images/mypic.png
```

You can now use `Virtual()` where you would `Content()`.

This solution is arguably excessive, but it is comprehensive.